# Se puede unir, combinar concatenar dos columnas?

Tags: c#

Que tal, tengo mi siguiente get y set:

```
  public virtual string Tp_Do
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string N_Rf
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Se puede unir en un solo get y set Tp_Do y N_Rf?

espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro que si, con una propiedad calculada:

```
public class Persona
{
    public string PrimerPropiedad { get; set; }
    public string SegundaPropiedad { get; set; }

    public string MiPropiedadCalculada
    {
        get { return PrimerPropiedad + SegundaPropiedad; }
    }
}
```